# httpUrlConnection .connect() error crash

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, facebook-android-sdk

In my application code

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        StringBuilder response = null;
        try {
            String request = ApplicationConstants.REQUEST_ABOUT_BASE_URI;
            URL url = new URL(request);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000); // millis
            conn.setConnectTimeout(15000); // millis
            conn.connect();
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: " + conn.getResponseCode() + " : " + conn.getResponseMessage());
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            String line;
            response = new StringBuilder();
            while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground: " + response.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
```

crash with error

http://pastebin.com/G6bXDfJJ

Unable to resolve host "tools.mysite.com"
But in my app constants REQUEST_ABOUT_BASE_URI write tools.mysyte.com/mobile.php?about

only real device and only Android 4.+. On Android 5.0 .connect() is ok.

Why?

Comment: Internet permissions in manifest file is include

Comment: This is a suggestion and not exactly an answer to your problem, but use `retrofit` instead of using `HttpURLConnection` and if you have time study `rxandroid`.

Comment: btw, you should post your logcat whenever you ask about an error in your code.

Comment: thx for answer. i have no time and i need resolve this problem

Comment: @gj_ this error line is all, what i looks in my stacktrace

Comment: Problem can be anything .the first one being you are trying the networking on main thread may be .post the log at here and we shall see

Comment: Try log.d rather than stack trace

Comment: you put the code in a separate thread, such as a Asynctask?